# showing a function of a specific form is right continuous

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have a question regarding showing some property of a specific function. The function $F(x)$ is defined as followed:

If $\mu$ is a finite measure on $\def\B{\mathcal{B}}$  (which is the Borel sets) and we define

$F(x) = \mu((-\infty, x])$, $x\in R$,

then F is increasing and right continuous, and $\mu_{F}=\mu$

Proof:

1) To show F(x) is increasing, I have $F(x+\epsilon) - F(x)  = \mu((-\infty, x+\epsilon]) - \mu((-\infty, x]) = \mu((-\infty, x+\epsilon] \setminus (-\infty,x]) ) = \mu((x, x+\epsilon])$ , where the very last term here i.e.$\mu((x, x+\epsilon])$ is bigger than zero since the set $(x, x+\epsilon)$ is non-empty, and measure is always bigger than or equal to zero.   So I think I have proved the "increasing" part.

2) To show F(x) is right continuous, I am not very sure if I have done it correctly.

I have $F(x) = \mu((-\infty, x]) = \mu( \bigcap \limits _{n=1}^{\infty} (-\infty, x+ \frac{1}{n}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} (-\infty, x+\frac{1}{n})  = F(x^{\texttt{+}})$

3) I am not sure how to start

My question is, does my proof for part 2 correct? basically I used the continuity from above property for the measure (i.e. $\mu( \bigcap \limits _{n=1}^{\infty} A_n) =  \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(A_n ) ) $ in this case, and also the finiteness of $\mu$ because it says $\mu$ is a finite measure. 
And how to start with the proof of part 3?

Also the book says this is an important function in Probability. Is it possible to know why this is important in probability?

thank you

Comment: Equality $\mu=\mu_F$ can only be proved if a definition of $\mu_F$ is provided. Function $F$ is a cumulative probability function (CDF). Probability measures on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B)$ are completely determined by their CDF. So if you know this function then you know the distribution.

Comment: thanks a lot for your comment drhab, but could you also comment on whether my proof for Part 2 is correct in the above?  thank you

Comment: I provided an answer on 2). Check yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning 2)

**Lemma**: Let $\mu$ be a measure on a measurable space $(X,\mathcal A)$ and let $(A_n)_n$ be a sequence of measurable sets with: $$A_1\subseteq A_2\subseteq A_3\subseteq\cdots\text{ and }A:=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$$
then:  $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(A_n)=\mu(A)$$

**Proof**: Setting $A_0=\varnothing$ and $B_n=A_n-A_{n-1}$ for $n=1,2,\dots$ we have $A=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} B_k$ where the $B_k$ are measurable and disjoint, and also $A_n=\bigcup_{k=1}^nB_k$.

Then: $$\mu(A)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(B_k)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\mu(B_k)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(A_n)$$

---

**Corollary**: Let $\mu$ be a **finite** measure on a measurable space $(X,\mathcal A)$  and let $(A_n)_n$ be a sequence of measurable sets with: $$A_1\supseteq A_2\supseteq A_3\supseteq\cdots\text{ and }A:=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$$
then:  $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(A_n)=\mu(A)$$

**Proof**: The lemma can be applied on sequence $(A_n^{\complement})_n$ and leads to $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(A_n^{\complement})=\mu(A^{\complement})$$

Then, on base $\mu(A_n^{\complement})=\mu(X)-\mu(A_n)$ and $\mu(A^{\complement})=\mu(X)-\mu(A)$ (note that here it is used that $\mu$ is a finite measure) we find:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(A_n)=\mu(A)$$

---

Applying this corollary we find: $$F(x)=\mu((-\infty,x])=\mu(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}(-\infty,x+\frac1n])=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu((-\infty,x+\frac1n])=\lim_{n\to\infty}F(x+\frac1n)$$